# ForEach-Object to look in subfolders

Tags: powershell

I Have this powershell script “copFiles.ps1” that looks in a txt file "Filestocopy.txt" for a list  and copies them to a destination

```
$source = "C:\Data\Filestocopy.txt"
$destination = "C:\Data\Models"
Get-Content $source | ForEach-Object {copy-item $_ $destination}
```

It’ll only copy the files if they’re in the same folder as the .ps1 file and it ignores subfolders, how can I get it to look in subfolders of the folder that its in, I gather I need to use the -recurse option but don’t know how to rewrite it so it works.
The .ps1 file is fired by a bat file.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how fast this will be, but you can give an array as the argument for the `-Path` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` add the `-Recurse` switch to dig out the files in subdirectories and simply pipe them along to `Copy-Item`. something like:

```
Get-ChildItem (Get-Content $Source) -Recurse |
Copy-Item -Destination $destination
```

You may also want to add the `-File` switch.

**Update**

Based on your comment I played around with this a a little more:

```
    $source = "C:\Data\Filestocopy.txt"
    $Destination = "C:\data\Models"
    
    # Get-ChildItem (Get-Content $Source) -Recurse |
    Get-ChildItem (Get-Content $Source) -Recurse -File |
    ForEach-Object{
        If( $_.Directory.FullName -eq $Destination )
        {   # Don't work on files already present in the destination
            # when the destination is under the current directory...
            Continue
        }        

        $FileNum = $null
        $NewName = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $_.Name
        
        While( (Test-Path $NewName) )
        {
            ++$FileNum
            $NewName = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath ($_.BaseName + "_" + $FileNum + $_.Extension)
        }
                    
        Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $NewName
    }
```

This will increment the destination file name in cases where a file by that name already exists in the destination.  If the destination is under the current directory it will prevent analyzing those files by comparing the path of the file to the destination.  Files must have unique names in a given folder so I'm not sure how else it can be handled.

Comment: OK great that does what is needed but theres an error for each file n the text list "Copy-Item : Cannot overwrite the item C:\CopyFiles\copytest\folder3\93568A.pdf with itself.
At C:\CopyFiles\copytest\CopyFileTool.ps1:4 char:48
+ ...  (Get-Content $source) -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination $destination
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\CopyFiles\copytest\folder3\93568A.pdf:String) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand"

Comment: Yes I got the same thing in my testing.  It means one of the files in the subdirectories has the same name as another file in another subdirectory.  In short a file by that name already exists in the destination directory.

Comment: I added some code that might help deal with the issue you mentioned in your comment.  If you are comfortable please mark the question answered, thanks.

Comment: many thanks for your help, i got it working I had the destination in the folders being searched so it was trying to copy & paste to the same folder, just moved the dest folder somewhere else